# Magento 2.3.5: Reset User ID numbers

Tags: magento2, php, database

I want to reset the "Users" ID numbers back to 1, 2, 3....

Under **System > Permissions > All users**

[image]

I'm presuming this is something that needs to be done in the DB.
How can I do this?

====================
UPDATE:

Trying to change the user ID from 3 to 1 using the following SQL command gives the following error.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_user`.`user_id` = 3;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

ERROR

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xyz_livesite`.`admin_passwords`, CONSTRAINT `ADMIN_PASSWORDS_USER_ID_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

================

UPADATE: 2

Doing the following fixed the issue.

1.

Disable 2fa from **Store > Configuration > Security > 2FA**

2.

In the DB > Table > **admin_passwords**

Uncheck - Enable foreign key checks
Run the following command

Change all user_id reference from 3 to 1, they probably hold previous passwords as well.

```
UPDATE `admin_passwords` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_passwords`.`password_id` = 49;
UPDATE `admin_passwords` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_passwords`.`password_id` = 50;
UPDATE `admin_passwords` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_passwords`.`password_id` = 51;
UPDATE `admin_passwords` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_passwords`.`password_id` = 52;
```

3. 

In the DB > Table > **admin_user**

Uncheck - Enable foreign key checks
Run the following command

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `user_id` = '1' WHERE `admin_user`.`user_id` = 3;
```

4. 

In the DB > Table > **authorization_role**

Where user_id is 3 change to 1 (this depends on your own setup, so change accordingly)

5.

Re-enable 2FA if needed and flush cache.

Answer (score -1):

Please clear the question with some relevant information, provide a brief description, and share your previous code and steps to reproduce what you perform.

Thanks

Comment: I think the question is on point, there is only one place in the admin panel where one can see "users", the rest along with the screenshot suffices.

Comment: Please revisit your question; you have asked to reset your user Id and also once you delete the user it is by default assigned the user with recent id. 
But what you can do is to check Magento database table and reset the entries of table accordingly.